# How to select different plotting functions at runtime in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, input

So here is my scenario:

I have a python script, call it `myscript.py`. Within this script, different types of data can be generated etc. When I run this script from the command line, I want to be able to input a 'plotting mode', like 1, 2, 3, etc. So far I know how to do that.

What I want to do with those plotting modes however, is where I am stuck.

Essentially, I want to say that if the plotting mode is 1, then execute a *particular* plotting routine, with say, 5 subplots, showing particular data in a certain way.

If the plotting mode is 2 lets say, then execute a completely different plotting routine, with 3 data types, showing them in a very particular way, etc etc.

I am not clear on how exactly go to about doing that. I suppose the easiest way is to simply map the plotting mode to an if/else statement, which calls particular functions, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the problem, if you know how to access the script parameters, why you can't use if for code flow ?

Comment: A skeleton code example will help understanding the question and then answering  it.

Comment: @EricNordeloGaliano It seems confusing I know. This is more a question of elegance than utility I am seeing. Basically, I have all options under a giant if-else statement now, where if the mode is 'blah', I run function 'plot_blah', and if the mode is 'foo', I run 'plot_foo'. But that means I have to define those functions as so. I was wondering if there was a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to map mode to function:

```
mode = ... # this is the mode you obtain from the call
lookup = {"1" : function1, "2" : function2, ...}
# call function from lookup depending on mode
lookup[mode]()
```

You could also obtain the function to be called via a string that contains the mode name

```
locals()["function{}".format(mode)]()
```

Of course this only works if `function1`, `function2` etc all take the same (or no) arguments. If you want to call different functions with different arguments, using `if/else` is probably a good way too.

Comment: Would the first option also be able to be used with each function having a different number and type of arguments?...

Comment: Well, e.g. via another lookup like `lookupargs = {"1" : (arg1, arg2), "2" : (arg33), ...}; lookup[mode](*lookupargs[mode])`.

Comment: Genius. One question - what is the * in *lookupargs[mode] for?

Comment: The asterix (`*`) unpacks a tuple or list. This is necessary because the function takes several arguments and not one single tuple. Also see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters